# Parameterised jade includes

Tags: pug

I want to have a mixin like this:

```
mixin foo(name)
  style
    include styles/#{name}.css
```

However this syntax is invalid. Is there any way to parameterise a Jade include like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not supported in version 2 probably will be.