# embedding Jade include variants

Tags: pug

In order to easily create a reference catalog of common UI components, I'd like to generate a static page from a series of markup fragments (one per component):

```jade
h2 List Group
p as provided by Bootstrap
+component("list_group")

h2 Panel
p also provided by Bootstrap
+component("panel")
```

This should expand to include said Jade file in three versions: raw, escaped HTML and unescaped HTML.

```jade
h3 Markup (HTML)
pre.lang-html
    include:escaped components/list_group

h3 Markup (Jade)
pre.lang-jade
    include:verbatim components/list_group

h3 Output
include components/list_group
```

```html
<h3>Markup (HTML)</h3>
<pre class="lang-html">
    &lt;ul class="list-group"&gt;
        &lt;li class="list-group-item"&gt;foo&lt;/li&gt;
        &lt;li class="list-group-item"&gt;bar&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;/ul&gt;
</pre>

<h3>Markup (Jade)</h3>
<pre class="lang-jade">
    ul.list-group
        li.list-group-item foo
        li.list-group-item bar
</pre>

<h3>Output</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">foo</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">bar</li>
</ul>
```

However, as far as I can tell, Jade does not support dynamic/parameterized includes*, so it's not quite as straightforward as expected.

Could I perhaps (ab)use a custom filter instead? (Looks like I'll have to write the `escaped` filter anyway.) Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

* though there are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881344/parameterised-jade-includes) [hints](https://github.com/pugjs/jade/issues/1312#issuecomment-70817811) that v2.0 actually does support this, I wouldn't know how

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

main.jade

```
- var condition=false
if condition
  include ./sub.jade
else
  include ./sub2.jade
```

sub.jade

```
p Hello World
```

sub2.jade

```
p 42
```

With condition=true

```
kluth@pc:~/$ jade main.jade && cat main.html
rendered main.html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

With condition=false

```
kluth@pc:~/$ jade main.jade && cat main.html
rendered main.html
<p>42</p>
```

Tested with jade 1.11.0

Comment: Thanks - however, I'm afraid I'm not sure how this solves the problem of `component($name)` resolving to various includes (`include components/$name`, same for `include:escaped` and `include:verbatim`).

Comment: I'm open to writing an extension, like the custom filter suggested in the OP - I'm just not sure that's the right way to go or where to start...

Comment: Okay. Can you give me a hint whatfor you'll need the three versions of your templates? So it may be easier to see what implementation would be adequate

Comment: For any given component, I want the rendered output along with the underlying markup, in both HTML and Jade format. (See the second code block above.) That way you can easily copy & paste whatever markup version you prefer and also see what the actual output looks like.